# jQuery link intermediate step

Tags: jquery

Is it possible in jQuery to have a link, when clicked, have an intermediate event occur?  For example, a very short video is played before going to the link's primary target.  I know I would most likely have to use .preventDefault() on the link for the first event, but how would I have the default action occur after the intermediate step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to bind to the window's beforeunload property like so:

```
 $(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
            <your code here>
        });
```

EDIT: Be sure to capture in your code if it's coming from that link or not.